# Python: Plotting on a tripolar grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot sea ice data with a spatial resolution of 200*360 on a tripolar grid. The data is from a fortran binary file. I want to look at the data looking down on the North pole so I went with a North Polar Stereographic Projection. When the data I plot the data, Northern Canada and Russia are distorted due to the Tripolar grid and I am wondering if there is a way to correct this. My code looks like:

```
aice = np.reshape(aice, (200,360))
m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=10,lon_0=270,resolution='l')
x=np.linspace(0,360,360)
y = np.linspace(-90, 90, 200)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
x, y = m(x,y)
mesh = m.contourf(x,y,aice, np.linspace(0,1,100), cmap=my_cmap)
```

The image I get:

[image]

Comment: Is your problem that your data looks to be in the wrong places, or that the continent outlines here don't look like they do in other North Polar Stereographic views from above the NP?

Comment: @cphlewis my problem is that the continent outlines don't look like they do in other North Polar Stereographic views from above the NP.

Comment: and without your data, how do they look? Is the problem the plotting, or the projection?

Comment: @cphlewis If I do m.drawcoastlines() the coastlines are offset from the data... If I change to Miller Cylindrical Projection I don't see the distortion that occurs in NPS, but again m.drawcoastlines() is offset from the data.